# Why the size of my database file is always 4KiB build through the Room library?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I build the database through the Room by this [guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0). This is my build code:

```
INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        NodesRoomDatabase.class, "nodes_database.db")
                        .build();
```

And I insert information by DAO:

```
public void insert(NodesData nodesData) {
    new InsertAsyncTask(nodesDao).execute(nodesData);
}

private static class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<NodesData, Void, Void> {
    private NodesDao asyncDao;

    public InsertAsyncTask(NodesDao asyncDao) {
        this.asyncDao = asyncDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(NodesData... nodesData) {
        asyncDao.insert(nodesData[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

After database build and insert something. I can find `nodes_database.db`, `nodes_database.db-shm` and `nodes_database.db-wal` under `data/data/<package name>/databases/` but the size of `nodes_database.db` is always only 4 KiB and has a empty table. But I can query all the contents of the database by using the Stetho debugging.

[The file size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlZTT.jpg)

Device: Oneplus 5, Android Oreo 8.1

So, what's wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's how SQLite works. If you want to query your database outside Android make sure to export both the .db and the .db-wal file.